# XML to POJO class mapping gives unrecognized field error in case of list elements with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am trying to map my XML string to POJO classes, it works fine for simple String and int but gives unrecognized field error in case of a list.

Sample Message
Unrecognized field "Events" (class com.example.fixinitiator.conversationSchema.Chat), not marked as ignorable

Here is my sample xml

```
<Chats>
         <Chat>
            <Identifier>11056</Identifier>
            <Topic/>
            <Disclaimer/>
            <Events>
                <Event>
                    <Type>Join</Type>
                    <User>GEHO</User>
                    <UTCTime>2022-04-13T10:10:27.985Z</UTCTime>
                </Event>
                <Event>
                    <Type>Join</Type>
                    <User>ZHOU</User>
                    <UTCTime>2022-04-13T10:10:27.985Z</UTCTime>
                </Event>
                <Event>
                    <Type>Send</Type>
                    <User>ZHOU</User>
                    <UTCTime>2022-04-13T10:10:32.063Z</UTCTime>
                    <Author>CounterpartyTypeTheirParty</Author>
                    <Message>
                        <MessageID>0</MessageID>
                        <Content>FX RECFM</Content>
                        <HasHighLight>false</HasHighLight>
                        <HasDeal>false</HasDeal>
                        <SystemText>NONE</SystemText>
                        <TextType>Online</TextType>
                    </Message>
                </Event>
                <Event>
                    <Type>Send</Type>
                    <User>GEHO</User>
                    <UTCTime>2022-04-13T10:10:38.987Z</UTCTime>
                    <Author>CounterpartyTypeOurParty</Author>
                    <Message>
                        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                        <Content>GEORGE&gt; YES FRIENDS?</Content>
                        <HasHighLight>false</HasHighLight>
                        <HasDeal>false</HasDeal>
                        <SystemText>NONE</SystemText>
                        <TextType>Online</TextType>
                    </Message>
                </Event>
                <Event>
                    <Type>Send</Type>
                    <User>ZHOU</User>
                    <UTCTime>2022-04-13T10:10:51.894Z</UTCTime>
                    <Author>CounterpartyTypeTheirParty</Author>
                    <Message>
                        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
                        <Content>HIHI FRD, SORRY FOR THE TYPO ERROR</Content>
                        <HasHighLight>false</HasHighLight>
                        <HasDeal>false</HasDeal>
                        <SystemText>NONE</SystemText>
                        <TextType>Online</TextType>
                    </Message>
                </Event>
                <Event>
                    <Type>Send</Type>
                    <User>ZHOU</User>
                    <UTCTime>2022-04-13T10:11:04.379Z</UTCTime>
                    <Author>CounterpartyTypeTheirParty</Author>
                    <Message>
                        <MessageID>3</MessageID>
                        <Content>MY AED TO CENTRAL OF UAE </Content>
                        <HasHighLight>false</HasHighLight>
                        <HasDeal>false</HasDeal>
                        <SystemText>NONE</SystemText>
                        <TextType>Online</TextType>
                    </Message>
                </Event>
                <Event>
                    <Type>Send</Type>
                    <User>ZHOU</User>
                    <UTCTime>2022-04-13T10:11:04.520Z</UTCTime>
                    <Author>CounterpartyTypeTheirParty</Author>
                    <Message>
                        <MessageID>4</MessageID>
                        <Content>(CBAUAEAAXXX),AE810010001000062101001 </Content>
                        <HasHighLight>false</HasHighLight>
                        <HasDeal>false</HasDeal>
                        <SystemText>NONE</SystemText>
                        <TextType>Online</TextType>
                    </Message>
                </Event>
                <Event>
                    <Type>Send</Type>
                    <User>ZHOU</User>
                    <UTCTime>2022-04-13T10:11:13.301Z</UTCTime>
                    <Author>CounterpartyTypeTheirParty</Author>
                    <Message>
                        <MessageID>5</MessageID>
                        <Content>FYI</Content>
                        <HasHighLight>false</HasHighLight>
                        <HasDeal>false</HasDeal>
                        <SystemText>NONE</SystemText>
                        <TextType>Online</TextType>
                    </Message>
                </Event>
                <Event>
                    <Type>Send</Type>
                    <User>ZHOU</User>
                    <UTCTime>2022-04-13T10:11:23.568Z</UTCTime>
                    <Author>CounterpartyTypeTheirParty</Author>
                    <Message>
                        <MessageID>6</MessageID>
                        <Content>OTHER DETAILS REMAIN THE SAME</Content>
                        <HasHighLight>false</HasHighLight>
                        <HasDeal>false</HasDeal>
                        <SystemText>NONE</SystemText>
                        <TextType>Online</TextType>
                    </Message>
                </Event>
            </Events>
        </Chat>
    </Chats>
```

Here is my POJO classes for this

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Chats {
    public Chat Chat;

    public Chats(@JsonProperty("Chats") com.example.fixinitiator.conversationSchema.Chat chat) {
        Chat = chat;
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Chat {

    public int Identifier;
    public String Topic;
    public String Disclaimer;
    @XmlElement(name = "Participants")
    public Participants Participants;
    private Events Events;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Events {
    public List<Event> Event;
}
```

```
@Setter
@Getter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Event {

    public String Type;
    public String User;
    public Date UTCTime;
    public String Author;
    public Message Message;


}
```